# Flash Builder - Platform conversion failed error during release build

Tags: air, compiler-errors, flash-builder, build-process, platform

This is a very annoying problem while generating release build files. Here is the steps I did while building:

1. Select Project > Export Release Build
2. Select Signed Native Installer
3. Import certificate
4. Click Next.

I always got the following error:

https://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-6524012-651585/build_error.png

> Platform conversion failed. Process exited with error 5. Output was
>   "[ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2
>   text="Unhandled exception Error: EndUpdateResource: Windows Error #5"
>   errorID=0]

I have the following setup:

OS: **Windows 8.1**
System type: **64-bit**
Flash Builder Version: **4.6 Premium**
Installed FB: **FlashBuilder_4_6_LS10.exe**

Please help. This is giving me a lot of headaches for a couple of days now.

Additionally, here's the stack trace:

> java.io.IOException: Platform conversion failed. Process exited with
>   error 5. Output was "[ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false
>   cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Unhandled exception Error:
>   EndUpdateResource: Windows Error #5" errorID=0] "   at
>   com.adobe.air.nai.NativePackager.conversionFail(NativePackager.java:222)
>   at
>   com.adobe.air.nai.NativePackager.invokePlatformConversion(NativePackager.java:203)
>   at
>   com.adobe.air.nai.NativePackager.createPackage(NativePackager.java:92)
>   at
>   com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.apollo.export.AIRNativeInstallerPackager.create(AIRNativeI
>   nstallerPackager.java:129)   at
>   com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ExportReleaseVersionManager.doExport(Ex
>   portReleaseVersionManager.java:586)   at
>   com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.releaseversion.ui.ExportReleaseVersionWizard$1.run(Exp
>   ortReleaseVersionWizard.java:208)

I also suspect this is because of the following settings:

**Eclipse.ini**

https://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-6525217-651726/eclipse.png

> ...
>   -startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
>    --launcher_library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502.jar
>   ...

Notice that the plugin used is not intended for x64 processors.

Answer (score 1):

@ActionScript3030 is correct, for anyone finding this later on, if you re-link your Library Paths (even if they look correct) this should rectify your issue.

The issue is caused by the links not being able to resolve to their GUID counterparts in your AppData/Local folder. This happens quite commonly when you create a new user profile and try to copy over your old user profiles information.

Answer (score 0):

I already figured this out. I created a virtual machine with windows 7 32bit operating system and I'm happy now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you initially created your project on a different system then try to compile it in another system, the class source and swc paths may not match. These paths could be there but not being implemented in code, so you will not get any run time errors while debugging, but it will give you the error 5 during compilation.
Solution:
Remove the idle paths not directly in use in your code. You can identify them by simply checking the path.

Answer (score 0):

Found the same issue when trying to use Microsoft Essential Security on my Windows 7 x32. When i uinstall it - problem gone. So try to check your firewall settings if stucking the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative solution (I'm on an x64 Windows and want to keep build exported for x64), in my case the error popped up when building the project with the AIR SDK defined in the app.xml (an older one, 3.9) and went away when I explicitly used a newer SDK (19).

(Disclaimer: I used the command line adt tool from the SDK to build, not Flash Builder).

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but might possibly help someone.

I had the same error recently with FlashDevelop. Figured out that the my path was too long. When I renamed some long folder and file names, the error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable UAC on Windows 8. Change it to "Never notify". The problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer Antro. I don't want to disable my UAC settings. I will still keep my computer protected and I'm sure this is not something to do with the security but a conversion issue from x64 to x32.